# What does the title「 僕だけの向こう側」mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, syntax, sentence

Can someone help me with possible translations for this title?

[僕]{ぼく}だけの[向]{む}こう[側]{がわ}: Boku dake no mukougawa

Also, can you explain why that would be the translation?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thanks for your first post here on Japanese Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, direct translations are off-topic, so you will likely need to revise your question to show your research effort. Please see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

向こう側 refers to a place beyond some landmark, e.g., 虹の向こう側 "somewhere over the rainbow", 地平線の向こう側 "a faraway place beyond the horizon". Judging from the explanation of the book of the same title (NSFW), this word seems to figuratively refer to an extremely fetish interest of 僕, a person who has "gone too far" in terms of sexual interest. I don't know what the best translation is, but the core idea is something like "the landscape only I can see", "I have gone this far", "beyond normality/sanity", etc.